# Orthogonal Projection Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I cannot seem to get this for my life. I know what the formula is to find the projection:
$$
\frac{u\cdot v}{\|u\|^2}  u
$$
I have this situation:

[image]

I have tried solving this but I seem to be doing something wrong...

My answer:
$$
\left(\frac{2}{3} , -\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)
$$
but this seems wrong...

Comment: You have the correct formula. What prevents you from using it? You just have to set $u$ to be equal to the first vector, the one that generates $L$.

Comment: I have 1/3 as my formula that I need to multiply it by vector L.  The answer I get is: 2/3 , -2/3   , -1/3    but this seems wrong...

Comment: That's because you divided by $\|u\|$ instead of $\|u\|^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So 
$$
u=(2,-2,-1)\quad\mbox{and}\quad v=(5,3,3).
$$
So 
$$
u\cdot v=2\cdot 5+(-2)\cdot 3+(-1)\cdot 3=10-6-3=1.
$$
And
$$
\|u\|^2=2^2+(-2)^2+(-1)^2=4+4+1=9.
$$
Hence the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $L$ is
$$
\frac{u\cdot v}{\|u\|^2}u=\frac{1}{9}(2,-2,-1)=\left(\frac{2}{9},-\frac{2}{9},-\frac{1}{9}\right).
$$

Comment: You're right... I was square rooting the 9 in the denominator for some reason....